# Ruby reading VB.NET generated data

Tags: ruby, vb.net

This is the general goal I am trying to achieve:

My VB.NET program will generate some Lists that may contain booleans, integers, strings, or more lists. I want the program to output a "file" which basically contains such data. <s>It is important that the file cannot be read by humans</s> Okay actually, fine, human-readable data wouldn't be bad.

Afterward, I want my Ruby program to take such file and read the contents. The Lists become arrays, and integers, booleans and strings are read alright with Ruby. I just want to be able to read the file, I might not need to write it using Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .Net you'd use a BinaryWriter, if you're using IronRuby you'd then use a BinaryReader.  If you're not using IronRuby, then perhaps...

contents = open(path_to_binary_file, "rb") {|io| io.read }

Why do you not want it to be human readable?  I hope it's not for security reasons...

Comment: Thanks for the idea! And, yeah, I've reconsidered it, and it might be okay to be human readable... sorry! What would I have to do if human-readable data was okay?

Comment: @Omega: if human readable data was OK, then I'd probably go with XML.  It's not very space efficient, but in most cases that's not really nearly as important as being able to deal with it easily.  I'd look into XML serialization and deserialization.

Comment: @Voldemort: was this answer useful?

Comment: I forgot why did I even need this back in 2011 lol. However I do know that this would have been the right answer back then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use JSON you can use the json.net nuget package.